# Opencart 2.0 How to duplicate filters?

Tags: filter, opencart, colorfilter

We are creating filters on Opencart 2.0. We gonna create the "color" filter, but the problem is that this filter will go on every category. Do we have to put this filter manually in each category or is there any way to duplicate filter or to applicate it directly to every category?

Thank You!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product color should be a [product attribute](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=139&t=50476), or an [option](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=2664), not a category. Then you can filter by attribute/option. You will likely need an extension to offer [attribute](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=filter%20attribute) or [option](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=filter%20option) filtering.

The color would be a product option if it is something that would not be a default variation of a product, and would modify its properties, i.e. price, different SKU # entirely. If an attribute, would be for informational purposes only.

Comment: You're welcome, roma. If this answer is a suitable one, please don't forget to mark it as such.